# calculating the area of hexagon without knowing its apothem

Tags: geometry, polygons

[image]
I am having a problem with task b.
I am afraid I can't find the area of the hexagon (and, therefore, can't find the requested value of probability) because there is no apothem for the hexagon on the picture.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127056/discussion-on-question-by-brilliant-calculating-the-area-of-hexagon-without-know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of a regular $n$-polygon with side $b$ is $\dfrac 1 4 b^2 \cot \dfrac \pi n$, which you can get from any halfway decent book of formulae (I use Schaum's "Mathematical Handbook" (1968)).

$\cot \dfrac \pi 6 = \dfrac {\sqrt 3} 3$.

The area of a polygon whose distance from side to centre is $r$ is $\pi r^2 \tan \dfrac \pi n$.

$\tan \dfrac \pi 5$ you can look up.

You should have enough to finish.

Answer (score 1):

As @YvesDaoust said, by knowing the side, we can determine the area. But if we have still problem, one can see hexagon as a union of 6 concentrated regular trigons (equilateral trianles), and sum the areas of them. Also for area of inner regular pentagon we can do similarly, but with 5 concentrated isosceles triangles, And even we can do this for left inner regular tetragon (square), with 4 ones, if we are computationary masochist!

Comment: I don't see the problem. The area of the hex is well defined. The area of the pentagon is also well defined. It remains to calculate the ratio between those areas. The result is a trivial exercise in algebra.

Comment: @PrimeMover - "The area of the pentagon is also well defined" - How is it well defined if we are not given the length of its side? We only know the apothem and the number of its sides, which is five. As far as I know, that's not enough for calculating the pentagon's area.

Comment: @brilliant It is absolutely enough. The area of a polygon whose distance from side to centre is $r$ is $\pi r^2 \tan \dfrac \pi n$.